# how to new DMatrix for XGBoost4J in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, xgboost

I have a RDD, which element is ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.LabeledPoint, like

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.LabeledPoint]
```

The function XGBoost.train needs DMatrix for training Data, I check out the xgboost source code and find a constructor function for DMatrix, likes that DMatrix(Iterator iter, String cacheInfo).
[DMatrix API](http://dmlc.ml/docs/javadocs/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/java/DMatrix.html)

However, I have no idea to construct Iterator for DMatrix.

Any solutions?

Besides: I can only use xgboost4j -v0.5 in spark1.5, so some functions in new versions can not use.

Comment: new DMatrix from local disk or HDFS is not suggested, because it's not convenient to save selected data everytime using spark-sql

Answer (score -1):

you can find a usage example on the xgboost github: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/jvm-packages/xgboost4j-example/src/main/scala/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/scala/example/spark/SparkWithRDD.scala

the relevant parts are:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{LabeledPoint => MLLabeledPoint}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{DenseVector => MLDenseVector}

 val trainRDD = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, inputTrainPath).map(lp =>
      MLLabeledPoint(lp.label, new MLDenseVector(lp.features.toArray)))
    val testSet = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, inputTestPath)
        .map(lp => new MLDenseVector(lp.features.toArray))
    // training parameters
    val paramMap = List(
      "eta" -> 0.1f,
      "max_depth" -> 2,
      "objective" -> "binary:logistic").toMap
    val xgboostModel = XGBoost.trainWithRDD(trainRDD, paramMap, numRound, nWorkers = args(1).toInt,
      useExternalMemory = true)
    xgboostModel.predict(testSet, missingValue = Float.NaN)
```

Comment: MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile is not convenient for spark-sql. I don't want to save selected data to HDFS everytime